# I am trying to put a play button in my image gallery

Tags: javascript, animation, image-gallery

I am trying to put a play button in my image gallery. I have a small pice of code that needs work,but my problem is getting the images to display one at a time. The code below brings up all the pictures at once. What I am wondering is if I can work this by classname or will I need to build an array and work from that.
This is the code that partialy works showing all at once. I think I am just missing something simple.

```
<script>
function slide_show() {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("s"),
        i = slides.length;

    for(i=0; i<15;  i++) {
        slides[i].style.visibility = "visible";
        slides[i].style.transition="visibility 5s ease 5s"
    }   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `setTimeout` to delay the movement and add some `opacity` to make them fade in:

```
var count = 0;
function slide_show() {
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("s"),
    i = slides.length;

  if (count < i) {
     slides[count].style.visibility = "visible";
     slides[count].style.opacity = "1";
     slides[count].style.transition="opacity 5s ease 5s"
     count++;
     setTimeout(slide_show, 500);
  }    
}
slide_show();
```

By changing the `opacity` numbers or the `setTimout` numbers - you can get different fade effects. Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uBfdc) to see it in action.

Comment: This solved part of the problem and gave me a possible solution to thee part.I have to say that this is the best response to a question I have seen yet, and you backed it up with a working example. Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function a little bit so it waits for the animation to finish:

```
<script>
var index = 0;
function slide_show() {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("s");

    if(index >= slides.length)
        return;

    slides[index].style.visibility = "visible";
    slides[index].style.transition = "visibility 5s ease 5s";

    setTimeout(slide_show, 10000); // Since it takes 10 seconds to finish your animation I put in 10000

    index++;
    }   
}
</script>
```